# check constraints for each column by passing a row

Tags: r, dynamic, apply, check-constraints, dynamic-columns

## Applying constraints for dynamic number of columns

I am using a data frame in which number of columns could be dynamic. I want to create a function to check constraints (mainly if each value lies between min and max, if given) on data. I will apply some functions to a combination of rows which will generate a single row. I want to pass this row to a constraint function and check if values of each column lies between min and max. For this I will give a constraint matrix which will have column names same as main data frame with first row as min and second as max. Some columns may have only min or only max. If a column is a character string in main data frame then both min and max value will be NA. Values not available will be NA. I want the function to return TRUE if all the given constraints are satisfied otherwise FALSE. If the row passed has more columns than the constraint matrix (columns generated during data manipulation), then only columns present in the constraint matrix should be checked. I also want the function to be fast and I am trying to use apply family functions, as this checking will happen many times.

I have tried ifelse() function and logical operators but it couldn't be applied if the number of columns and constraints are dynamic.

```r
# Function to Check Constraints
# df is a dataframe consisting of only one row on which constraints are to be checked
check_cons = function(df){
    df = c(df)
    return(ifelse( df$col1 > cons_col1_min, ifelse( df$col1 < cons_col1_max, ifelse( df$col2 > cons_col2_min, ifelse( df$col2 < cons_col2_max, ifelse( df$col3> cons_col3_min , ifelse( df$col3< cons_col3_max,T, F), F), F), F), F), F))    
}
# But this function cannot be used for dynamic number of constraints.
```

What I am trying to do will be something like the following.

```
#Constraint Matrix
col1 col2 col3 col4 
4    7    NA   NA   
10   NA   17   NA

#I can have an input row like this
#Case 1:
col1 col2 col3 col4 
5    11    16   A   
# Passing this row should return values TRUE as it follows all the constraints
# col4 could have any max or min as both values not given and it is a character data
# col2 has a min constraint and col3 has a max constraint.

#Case 2:
col5 col1 col2 col3 col4
23   5    11    16   A  

# For this row constraints for col5 will not be checked as it is not given in the constraint matrix
# Positions of columns could be jumbled in the passed dataframe with one row
# This will also return the value as TRUE.
```

**Please let me know any type of solution that comes to your mind**
An approximate solution will also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
check_cons<-function(inp,constr) { # allows you to define both the dataframe and the constraints
  constr<-constr[,!sapply(constr,function(x) all(is.na(x)))] # remove constraint columns that are all NA because they don't matter
  inp<-inp[,names(constr)] # remove columns that don't appear in the constraints matrix, and reorder the input according to the constraints
  all(inp>constr[1,], inp<constr[2,],na.rm=TRUE) # check the conditions
}
```

Here's a similar solution that takes data.frames with more than one line, and checks the constraints for each of them using `apply`, outputting a vector of TRUEs and FALSEs:

```
check_cons<-function(inp,constr) {
  constr<-constr[,!sapply(constr,function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
  inp<-inp[,names(constr)]
  suppressWarnings(apply(inp, 1, function(inp) all(inp>constr[1,], inp<constr[2,],na.rm=TRUE)))
}
```

(Note that using `apply` transforms the data.frame into a matrix, in which case, if any of the columns is a character class, ALL columns will become character. That's why I removed columns with only NA from the constraints. Alternatively, you can use "as.numeric" before the inp arguments in the above `apply`.)